# Using MySQL: Update field with values using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have a main table and an index table. Both tables share a common primary field called "L_Status". I want to update the data in the main table from "L_Status" values (integers) into "L_StatusLV" (readable text values) based on the reference in the index table called "status". Here is the code I've entered into PHPmyAdmin to accomplish this:

```
UPDATE markers.L_Status 
FROM markers
INNER JOIN STATUS ON markers.L_Status = status.L_Status
WHERE  markers.L_Status = status.L_StatusLV
```

PHPmyAdmin returns the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM markers INNER JOIN STATUS ON markers.L_Status = status.L_Status WHERE ma' at line 2

Any advice on the sytax error here?

Comment: It should get the text value pair of the primary key (L_Status) in the 'status' table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL's `UPDATE` `JOIN` syntax differs from SQL Server's (which looks like what you have):

```
UPDATE
  /* First join the tables */
  markers 
  INNER JOIN status ON markers.L_Status = status.L_Status
/* Then specify the new value in the SET clause */
SET markers.L_Status = status.L_StatusLV
```

However, as you noted above the current values are integers. If the column `markers.L_Status` is an `INT` column rather than a `CHAR/VARCHAR` as I assume the human-readable column is, this won't work.

Visit [MySQL's `UPDATE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for the full syntactic details. In particular, the *`table_references`*.