# Updating two tables with an inner join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two tables one is **question** and other is **answer**.

**Question table** has fields as

```
question_id, question, type, answer_id.
```

**Answer table** has fields as

```
answer_id, question_id, comment, rating, doctor_id
```

Now I want to update the answer belongs to the question where doctor_id. For this I tried to write this query :

```
update question q 
set q.question = 'dmvvnnv',a.comment = 'covonfvk',a.rating = 5 
INNER JOIN answer a on q.answer_id = a.answer_id 
WHERE a.doctor_id = 8
```

But it is giving me the syntax error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN answer a on q.answer_id = a.answer_id WHERE
>   a.doctor_id = 8' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MySQL: Update field with values using Inner Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006856/using-mysql-update-field-with-values-using-inner-join)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables?noredirect=1&lq=1 which would have been a better dupe target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL `UPDATE` with `JOIN` syntax is different, the `SET` part should come after the `JOIN`

Use the following query to update the entries:

```
UPDATE question q
INNER JOIN answer a ON a.answer_id = q.answer_id
SET q.question = 'dmvvnnv'
    ,a.comment = 'covonfvk'
    ,a.rating = 5
WHERE a.doctor_id = 8
```

Comment: Exactly like @Arulkumar said. An earlier Post for this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables

Comment: by this all questions are getting updated for the doctor_id 8. How can we update the single question? @Arulkumar

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
UPDATE question q INNER JOIN answer a on q.answer_id = a.answer_id 
SET q.question = 'dmvvnnv',a.comment = 'covonfvk',a.rating = 5
WHERE a.doctor_id = 8
```

Comment: gives error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM question q
INNER JOIN answer a on q.answer_id = a.answer_id WHERE a.doctor' at line 2 @AT-2016

Comment: by this all questions are getting updated for the doctor_id 8. How can we update the single question? @AT-2016

Comment: There is a unique id in the question table. Just use it to update a single row like ques_id - 1, 2, 3, 4, so on.